# Copy files from dying hdd and create log under Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, file-transfer

How can I copy files from dying HDD and also create a log file which will include the status of given file (if it was successfully copied or not?). My goal is to run the backup tool without user interaction and then check log. I'm aware of tools such as dd and ddrescue but this is not what I want because those tools require free HDD which I do not have at the moment. I have enough space on another HDD but I cannot format it. I know that dd, ddrescue can clone the disk into the file but this file needs to be mounted and further processed which is further work.

Comment: If you want to log anything `script` is your friend.

Comment: so if I will run cp under script and cp wont be able to read broken file will copy process continue?

Comment: Script will not change anything except logging the output.

Comment: so question is if cp will continue?

Comment: Aye. Which means you might want to consider something other than cp. IO would suggest dd rescue but you already seem to have discounted that due to lack of space.